# Color all element's background and text on page with SCSS in Ionic3

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework, sass

I am attempting to recolour all element's background and text of a page in SCSS in an ionic 3 project.

The SASS code I am using at the moment is:

```
* {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

The problem is that only the background colour is changed. The problem is that the text stays in default colour.

I would look for a different attribute to overwrite but the "color" attribute works in html styling. The following HTML code performs the wanted changes:

```
<ion-card-header style="color: white">
    Title
</ion-card-header>
```

The "color" attribute also works on all other elements that need to be recoloured, but I don't feel like the solution is to add the HTML styling to every single element.

How can I overwrite all text colours for this page using SCSS (just like the already working background)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing a `specifity` issue that's why color is not working on some elements, as you can read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) :

> Universal selector (*), combinators (+, >, ~, ' ') and negation
>   pseudo-class (:not()) have no effect on specificity.

So if you want to still use * as a selector you may add **!important** like this :

```
* {
    background-color: black;
    color: white!important;
}
```

> When an important rule is used on a style declaration, this
>   declaration overrides any other declarations.